# UIView finish touches programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, touchesmoved

The matter is, I'm making a drag and drop iPad game.
Moving my view like that

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = CGPointMake(pt.x - _xOffset, pt.y - _yOffset);
}
```

But in some moment I want to stop dragging my view and put it to some location.
I'm stuck on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to disable the touch handling when you go to position the view finally. Probably the easiest thing to do it to add an instance variable (like `BOOL draggingEnabled`) which you use to choose how to handle the user interaction. Set the flag to YES when you start a new touch and to NO when you move to the final position. Check the value in `touchesMoved` before you change the view center.